# How to set float type in loopback 4

Tags: typescript, loopback, loopback4

I am using following code in loopback 4 to have number (float) field, but I am not getting float in my DB:

```
@property({
  type: 'number',
  jsonSchema: {
    format: 'float',
  },
})
Field: number;
```

I am using `MySQL` database and loopback migrate with `int(11)` type ([docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/LoopBack-types.html#overview) just have `number`)

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [dataType](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/MySQL-connector.html#fixed-point-exact-value-types) as:

```
@property({
  type: 'number',
  dataType: 'FLOAT'
})
Field: number;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Loopback 4, default migration reads this from database specific settings.

Float can be used like this for [postgresql connector](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/PostgreSQL-connector.html).

```
@property({
    type: 'number',
    postgresql: {
      dataType: 'float',
      precision: 20,
      scale: 4,
    },
})
rating?: number;
```